# jquery mobile change page transition using velocity.js

Tags: jquery, mobile, velocity.js

My multipage jquery mobile android app uses transitions to change page with swipe gestures, something like:

```
$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "#mynewpage", {transition: "slide"});
```

Performances are really too slow, so I was considering to use velocity.js. I know how to use it to animate an element, but I cannot figure out how to apply it in a page container change event, and in general for all transitions included in widget event (such opening popups, changing pages, etc..)

Comment: Were you able to use velocity then? I'm also looking at this.